# Create a vector of objects in r

Tags: r

The output of a for loop consists of a large number of dataframes. I want to combine them in a single dataframe using the function `qpcR::cbind.na()`. For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a=1:2, b=1:2)
df2 <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=1:5)
df3 <- data.frame(a=1:3, b=1:3)
library(qpcR)
M <- t(qpcR:::cbind.na(df1, df2, df3))
 1 2  3  4  5
a 1 2 NA NA NA
b 1 2 NA NA NA
a 1 2  3  4  5
b 1 2  3  4  5
a 1 2  3 NA NA
b 1 2  3 NA NA
```

I want to put the output of my for loop inside this function automatically to create M. The following doesn't do the job:

```
n = 3 # number of loop iterationns
B <- c()
for (i in 1:n) {
B[i] <- paste("df[[", i, "]]", sep = "")
}
P <- print(paste(B, collapse=","), quote = F)
M <- t(qpcR:::cbind.na(P))
```

Neither do these:

```
M <- do.call(t(qpcR:::cbind.na()), list(P))
M <- lapply(P, t(qpcR:::cbind.na()))
```

How can I create the vector of objects `c(df1, df2, df3)` without resorting to copy and paste `P` inside `qpcR::cbind.na()`?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are using cbind from qpcR as opposed to base cbind?

Comment: My data frames may differ in nrow

Comment: What is `n`? It's not defined above.

Comment: @SantiagoGuallar Can you please update your question with the desired output, given the (nice, little) sample data you provided.

Comment: Now n and the desired output are given in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like this is what you are looking for.  The `get()` function is the key to this solution. ope it helps!

```
M <- df1
for (i in 2:3) {
  new_df <- paste("df", i, "", sep = "")
  M <- qpcR:::cbind.na(M, get(new_df))
  }
t(M)
```

Comment: It works pretty fine. It's gonna be helpful in many situations. Thank you!